# How to make a visualizer of surfaces with AUGMENTED REALITY in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, arcore, visualizer

I'm new here. Currently, I'm doing in a work about augmented reality to visualize quadratic surfaces of math functions. 
The idea is that the student (user) first visualizes the xyz plane with a surface generated by default (for example an elliptic paraboloid) and then the student can enter their equations to add more surfaces and see the intersection formed between the surfaces.

The problem is that I'm not sure what tools or techniques I can use to make this application in unity.

It would be very helpful if you know about jobs that have done this, and how they developed it.
P.s. Currently, I'm using ARCore to make augmented reality. I also heard about using Android studio and OpenGL but what do you recommend ...

Comment: You might be better off asking this question on the unity forums https://forum.unity.com/

Comment: @Mario, requests for API recomendations considered here as off-topic. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. ". [Related post on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199411/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-finding-general-software-that-meets-certain-req)